# Why do we need to specific size during vector image generation in Android Studio?

Tags: android

I first thought the purpose of Vector assets is that, it enables us to scale up/ scale down without compromise image quality.

***If so, may I know why do we need to specific size during vector image generation in Android Studio?***

[image]

I tend to generate 2 different sizes of Vector.

### 24x24

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M19,2h-4.18C14.4,0.84 13.3,0 12,0c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v16c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,2c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1s-0.45,1 -1,1 -1,-0.45 -1,-1 0.45,-1 1,-1zM19,20L5,20L5,4h2v3h10L17,4h2v16z"/>
</vector>
```

### 96x96

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="96dp"
    android:height="96dp"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#FF000000"
        android:pathData="M19,2h-4.18C14.4,0.84 13.3,0 12,0c-1.3,0 -2.4,0.84 -2.82,2L5,2c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v16c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h14c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2L21,4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zM12,2c0.55,0 1,0.45 1,1s-0.45,1 -1,1 -1,-0.45 -1,-1 0.45,-1 1,-1zM19,20L5,20L5,4h2v3h10L17,4h2v16z"/>
</vector>
```

The content looks same except for `android:width` and `android:height` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a full explaination, but here is what I think.

Some image containers really depend on the size of the drawable to draw the image correctly. They cannot use `viewportHeight` and `viewportWidth`, so `width` and `height` is what they look for.

In my case, when loading a `Marker` on `GoogleMap`, I cannot change the size of marker programatically. The map use the exact size of the drawable to be the size of the marker. When I use `VectorDrawable` for the marker, I have to modify the `width` and `height` to the marker size I want.

The `GoogleMap Marker` is the image container I am talking about that always need the exact source's size.